# OpenCV (in C++) to MQTT broker

Tags: python, c++, json, opencv

My goal is to publish from OpenCV (C++) a JSON stream of (x, y) coordinates to an MQTT broker. I'm confused as to a good way to transmit the JSON data to MQTT from OpenCV.

I currently have an MQTT broker that manages a JSON message queue between a Python publisher script on Computer 1 and a Javascript client script on Computer 2. I have Computer 3 running OpenCV and need to send many small JSON blobs of (x, y) coordinates in near real-time to the MQTT broker.

I initially considered continuously writing coordinates from OpenCV to a local text file, which is then continuously read by a Python MQTT publisher script that runs in parallel. However, there are issues around file locking and it seems that writing to disk is unnecessary.

Ideally, I'm hoping for the stream of coordinates to stay in memory and published to the MQTT broker often, say every 10ms. I'm struggling to find a way to use stdin/stdout to work between the OpenCV code and a Python publisher script.

Your guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned a python script for a publisher.

Here is the publisher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# This is the Publisher

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost",1883,60)
client.publish("topic/test", "Hello world!", qos=0, retain=False)
client.disconnect()
```

Here is a subscriber:
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

```
# This is the Subscriber

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("topic/test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  if msg.payload.decode() == "Hello world!":
    print("Yes!")
   client.disconnect()

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost",1883,60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what parts you are missing, but you basically want:

```
#include "mqtt.h"
...
// Start up
mqtt_broker_handle_t *broker = mqtt_connect(client_name, ip_addr, port);
...
...
// Update broker
mqtt_publish(broker, topic, msg, QoS1);
```